# Android Quiz Application Count Down Timer

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

Hi guys i am still working on my capstone project i am working for a quiz application and i need to put a timer which will end the quiz when ever the timer is 0
i need a code where when the activity starts the timer starts too and when it ends it goes to the result activity i already have a code for my quiz activity which contains the answers and questions here is the code please help me where and what to put to achieve that count down timer ur help would be so much appreciated

```
package org.intercode.lifeatceu;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;

public class levelone extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tv1, tvCred, tvQuestion, tvTime;
Button btNext;
RadioButton rb1, rb2;
RadioGroup rg;

String questions [] = {"Ma. Cristina D. Padolina is CEU's President", "Carlito B. Olaer is the V.P of CEU", "CEU's VISION is to sting every enemy", "One of CEU's Mission is to promote creative and scholarly academic"};
String answer [] = {"True", "False", "False", "True"};
HashSet numbers = new HashSet();


int flag = 0;
Random rnd = new Random();
int flag2 = 0 ;
int score = 0;
int correct = 0;
int wrong = 0;
int coins = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_levelone);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Intent inquiz = getIntent();
   final int credit = inquiz.getIntExtra("passedCredits", 0);
    String TotalCoins = String.valueOf(credit);



    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tvCred = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCred);
    tvQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
    tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
    rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);
    btNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btNext);
    flag2 = rnd.nextInt(4);
    numbers.add(flag2);



    tvQuestion.setText(questions[flag2]);
    tvCred.setText(TotalCoins);

    btNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioButton uans = (RadioButton) findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
            if (ansText.equalsIgnoreCase(answer[flag2]))
            {
                while (numbers.contains(flag2))
                {
                    flag2 = rnd.nextInt(4);
                }
                correct++;
                coins++;

            }
            else
            {
                wrong++;
            }
            flag++;
            flag2 = rnd.nextInt(4);
            if (flag < questions.length)
            {
                tvQuestion.setText(questions[flag2]);
            }
            else
            {
                score = correct;
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Results.class);
                in.putExtra("passedCredits", credit);
                in.putExtra("passedWrong", wrong);
                in.putExtra("passedCorrect", correct);
                in.putExtra("passedCoins", coins);
                startActivity(in);
            }

        }
    });
}

}
```

i hope there would be a way to put the timer inside this codes :P

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Timer;
```

And you should put something like this in your onResume():

`Timer timer = new Timer();`

```
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intentToResultActivity = new Intent(context, ResultActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intentToResultActivity);
        }
    }, 10000);`
```

Where "context" is the this of the current activity and ResultActivity.class is the name of the Activity you want to show after the timer runs out.

Comment: where will the timer be displayed? as textview or?

Comment: This code will set up a hidden timer that will only execute once and its role is to show the result activity. If you want to have a countdown timer you can use a similar code and a text view. The difference is that you should provide a second parameter in the timer task, for example " }, 0, 1000" That way the code will be executed immediately and will repeat every 1000 ms. In the body of the code you can decrement the value which the text view is holding.

Comment: uhm can u teach me how to do it? coz there is not tutorial in youtube so i cannot have the idea of it

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here is the code for the countdown timer. You should examine it and integrate it for your own needs:

You have two activities - Activity1 for the countdown and Activity2 which is the result activity after the timer runs out.

Activity1.java:

```
package com.example.emily.countdowntimer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context = this;
    Timer timer;
    int countdownValue = 10;
    TextView countdownTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

        //this view will hold the countdown value
        countdownTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countdown);

        //we create a new timer and then schedule a task which will execute every one second
        //(it will change the value of the text view)
        timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        countdownValue--;
                        countdownTextView.setText("" + countdownValue);

                        //when the value of the countdown reaches 0, we start the result activity:
                        if (countdownValue == 0) {
                            Intent intentToResultActivity = new Intent(context, Activity2.class);
                            context.startActivity(intentToResultActivity);
                            timer.cancel();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        },0, 1000);

    }

}
```

activity_1.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Activity1">

    <TextView android:text="Time Left:" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:textSize="28sp"/>

    <TextView android:text="10" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id = "@+id/countdown"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#ff111d"
        android:textSize="58sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity2.java:

```
package com.example.emily.countdowntimer;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
    }

}
```

activity_2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#406447">

    <TextView android:text="Result Activity" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="28sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.emily.countdowntimer" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity2"
            android:label="Result Activity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

That is all the code you need. I suggest you just put it in your Android Studio and see how it works. It is a lot easier to understand code when you play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code for countdown timer:

```
    long durationSec = (duration * 60L);
    final long durationInMilliSec = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(durationSec);

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer= new CountDownTimer(durationInMilliSec, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tvQuestionAnswerTimer.setText("" + String.format("%02d : %02d : %02d ",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
        }
        public void onFinish() {
                Toast.makeText(this,Time's up!, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }.start();
```

In this code

`duration` is long type minutes.

`durationSec` is long type seconds.

`durationInMilliSec` is long type milliseconds.

Then milliseconds converts to hours,minutes and seconds for countdown timer.

I hope its work for you.